# SSRS 2008 Credentials used to run this report are not stored

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, credentials

I created a report in SSRS, and deployed it. I went to the properties of the report the Process option, and tried to set up Cache a temporary copy of the report and got an error 'Credentials used to run this report are not stored.' I get the same error if I go to Snapshot Options and try to select any of the options there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the error, you need to set up the report **Data Source** similar to the following:

[image]

If you're not storing credentials you cannot cache reports or create snapshots.

With cached reports, a temporary copy is created when a user runs a report and this can be used for subsequent runs of the report. Since this could be performed by different users, the only way this can work is if the same connection is used to the Data Source each time; it must be independent of whoever is running the report when the copy is cached.

Same principle for snapshots; no guarantee who will run reports based off the snapshot, so the Data Source connection must be independent of the user running the report, i.e. stored at the Data Source level.